# how to save an image from a page to a folder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an image in my index.html page. I want javascript or jquery to download this image automatically in my a folder by clicking the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <title>save image from a page</title>
</head>

   <body>

   <img src="car.jpg"/>
   <button>save Image in my folder</button>
   <!-- the name of the folder is : (saveImage) :  and it is in the same 
   place with my index.html-->

   <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
   <script>
   $("button").click(function()
   {
      // download image from the index.html to my folder (saveImage)
   });
  </script>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with php? You can do this very easily with php..

Comment: Abdush Samad Miah : yes i'm familiar with php..so can you say me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I tried following and checked it with firefox and chrome. Worked fine with both the browsers. Used HTML5 'download' attribute to your links.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>save image from a page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <a style="display:none;" href="car.png" download>save Image in my folder     </a>
<img src="car.png"/>
<!-- the name of the folder is : (saveImage) :  and it is in the same 
place with my index.html-->
<button>save Image in my folder</button>
 <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("button").click(function()
{
   $('a')[0].click();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you don't have downloaded jquery library add this  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>